# Connect GraphQL resolvers to database

Tags: database, typescript, graphql

I'm making a little project that consists in a single User table made in Prisma migrate. i'm using typescript and graphQl, and I know that you can pass the instanciated prisma client to a context in my graphQLHTTP (using express-graphQL), but I was not able to receive it in my schema file. I'll show the schema, and my server.

Some comments in the code shows where I'm having the problem

I want to pass the prisma client as my context so I can use it in my resolvers. I tried to find examples, but I haven´t find any while looking for it. All the examples use graphql yoga or something like that, and I want to know how to do it, if someone knows how to do it please give me some help

server.ts

```
import express from 'express'
import { graphqlHTTP } from 'express-graphql'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const schema = require('./schemas/schema')
const router = require('../router/router')
const app = express()

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

app.use(router)
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  graphiql: true,
  schema,
  context: prisma <--- I wanted to pass it here. 
}))

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server started at 4000'))
```

schema.ts

```
import {
   GraphQLObjectType,
   GraphQLString,
   GraphQLList,
   GraphQLID,
   GraphQLSchema
} from 'graphql'


const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
  })
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQuery',
  fields: {
    users: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      resolve(context, args, parent) {
        //What I wanted to do:
        //return context.db.user.findMany() <--- Example

        console.log(context) <-- logs undefined
      }
    }
  }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
})
```

Comment: What gave you the impression that context is the first parameter passed to the resolver?

Comment: Is it the error??

Comment: Do I need to define an interface to everything that I get in my log?? I'm using typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for the resolver function can be found [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype) in the docs. If you're using an IDE like VS Code, you can also lookup the relevant TypeScript definition directly.

```
type GraphQLFieldResolveFn = (
  source?: any,
  args?: {[argName: string]: any},
  context?: any,
  info?: GraphQLResolveInfo
) => any
```

The first parameter is the "parent" value returned by the parent field's resolver. Then the field arguments. Then the context.

So you need to make sure you're accessing the correct parameter.

Additionally, you should set your context like this:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  graphiql: true,
  schema,
  context: { prisma },
}))
```

This way, if you need to add additional properties to your context, you won't have to refactor your existing code.